# After local Notification trigger the device date and time changes to default

Tags: android, date

In our application we using `local notification`, that will trigger every `Monday`. For testing purpose I changed the device `date and time` to advance one week(Next Monday). As expected we received the notification.

Unexpectedly we faced this issue as the device date and time automatically changed to current date and time once the notification trigger.

It occurs in some of the devices like `Nexus 6 and Samsung Galaxy S5`.

Can anyone tell us what went wrong ?
It is OS related issue or hardware related issue ?
Suggest any solution  to overcome this....

Answer (score 1):

At last we found the issue is due to OS specific. When we tried to set the date point to future that is advance over 80 days, the device itself changing the date automatically to current date when device has internet connection